# Pythonic way to write wrapper functions

Tags: python

Let's say I have a function `foo` that gets a few parameters

```
def foo(width, height, depth=0):
    ...
```

I want to write a wrapper function that gets all of `foo`'s parameters and passes them on, e.g.

```
def goo(width, height, depth=0):
    ...
    foo(width, height, depth)
    ...
```

But this is ugly, since I have to repeat the variables *and* the default values.

**What's the idiomatic way to do this in python?**

A few options I thought about:

1. passing to `goo` a dictionary called `foo_params` and calling `foo(**foo_params)` but then is error prone since I don't know
   if all the arguments are there
2. writing another wrapper for foo that checks if the params with default values are `None` and if so doesn't pass them
3. Putting the default values as constants so I won't repeat them

Comment: You can just use `*args` and `**kwargs` (similar to your option 1, but no need to pass a dict to `goo()`). If a parameter is missing, the error will bubble up from `foo()` instead of `goo()`. Since they have the same function signature, that shouldn't be too confusing.

Comment: i would recommend using `*args` and `**kwargs` as well. its the most general method and widely accepted

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `*args` and `**kwargs` syntax to pass an unknown amount of arguments and/or keyword arguments:

```
>>> def dec(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print('decorated function')
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner

>>> @dec
def func(a, b):
    return a + b

>>> func(1, 2)
decorated function
>>>
```

One downside to using `*args` and `**kwargs` is that you'll lose the orginal function signature of the decorated function. eg:

```
>>> help(func)
Help on function inner in module __main__:

inner(*args, **kwargs)

>>>
```

The solution is to use [`functools.wraps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps). It basically copies of the data from the decorated function to the wrapper function:

```
>>> from functools import wraps
>>> 
>>> def dec(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print('decorated function')
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner

>>> @dec
def func(a, b):
    return a + b

>>> func(1, 2)
decorated function
>>>
```

A you can see below, if you now do `help(func)` the original signature for `func` will be displayed:

```
>>> help(func)
Help on function func in module __main__:

func(a, b)

>>>
```

Comment: @ChristianDean does this allow me to use the params in the wrapper function? I mean, without using `kwargs.get()`

Comment: @Dotan Yes. You no longer have to explicitly pass each argument and/or keyword argument to your function. All you're required to do is unpack the arguments tuple `args` and the keyword argument dictionary `kwargs` into the call to the decorated function. Python will handle the reset.

Comment: I needed to change the second line of `inner` to `return func(*args, **kwargs)` in order to make this work.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for [functools's partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)  function:

```
from functools import partial

def foo(a,b):
    return a + b

goo = partial(foo, b = 1)

goo(5)   # returns 6
```

Comment: I don't believe the OP is looking for currying, which is a different concept than wrapping